# Returning From User Defined Function is Crashing My Program

Tags: c, function, crash, return

So what I'm aiming to do is take a menu option as input, inside the function
`getMenuInput();` (1-4) and return it to main() to be used with a switch case. This code is simplified, but I intend to poll for two vectors and perform operations on them. I can't for the *life* of me work out why it stops when returning from the function, without reaching the switch case. I've even tried printing text in the line immediately after the return and I get no output.

As a side note you only get 3 chances to input a correct menu option otherwise the program exits and prints an error. Could this (or rather, my method of achieving this) be the problem here?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* This is a structure to hold the two parts
of the vector in a single variable        */
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
} vect;

char getMenuInput(void);

int main(void)
{
    /* declaration of variables */
    vect vector1, vector2;
    char menuInput = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while ((counter < 3) && (menuInput == 0))
    {
        printf("--- Menu ---\n"
           "1 Add two vectors\n"
           "2 Subtract two vectors\n"
           "3 Calculate Euclidian Distance\n"
           "4 Exit the program\n"
           "  Please select an option (1, 2, 3, or 4): ");

        menuInput = getMenuInput();  /* 3 chances */

        switch (menuInput)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("You selected 'Add'\n");
                break;
            }/* Add vectors */

            case 2: 
            {
                printf("You selected 'Subtract'\n");
                break;
            }/* Subtract vectors */

            case 3: 
            {
                printf("You selected 'Euclidian Distance'\n"); 
                break;
            }/* Euc Distance */

            case 4: 
            {
                printf("You selected 'Exit'\n"); 
                break;
            }/* exit */

            default: 
            {
                printf("  >Invalid option!\n");
                menuInput = 0;
                ++counter;
            }
        }
    }
    if (counter == 3)
        printf("Program error - Too many invalid inputs");
    else
        return (0);

        /* Receive the two vectors (float or int, +ve or -ve */
        /* This repeats until they're entered correctly */


        /* Find the solution, operation found in the menu */
        /* Float, 2dp precision */
}

char getMenuInput(void)
{
    char temp;
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    return (temp);
}
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
--- Menu ---
1 Add two vectors
2 Subtract two vectors
3 Calculate Euclidian Distance
4 Exit the program
  Please select an option (1, 2, 3, or 4): 1

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 870ms)
```

Please help. I'm ripping my hair out.

Comment: Wrong format specifier to scanf. Voting to close as simple typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char temp;
scanf("%d", &temp);
```

`temp` is a char (1 byte) but you are trying to read an integer (probably 4 or 8 bytes) into it? That's undefined behavior that could quite likely cause a crash.

Comment: I tried changing it to %c rather than %d but unfortunately the output goes haywire - one input is read as 2 subsequent inputs and the switch case is seemingly ignored :/

Comment: On another note, I changed the function to type int and menuInput to type int and it's working. I was attempting to use char to save some memory (for optimisation's sake). Any ideas why it wasn't working?

Comment: @NathanLocke you should read up on how [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf) works. %c does not what you think it does. Also optimization should be done if neccessary after the functionality is finished.

Comment: Sound advice, I'll make the code work before I try mixing it up. It was my understanding that %c reads one character of type char, and char can store integers up to 254 or a single ASCII coded letter. I'll do some more research.

Answer (score -1):

Declaration of Variables may be wrong.
You have to use vector 1,vector 2 instead of Vect during creating structure. And also you haven't use it in this code. So why you creat it?

Comment: The code has been simplified, and I've basically included what's important for the question. There's a lot more code but I've made it simpler to follow.